# function for two numpy array costume multiplication

Tags: python, numpy, matrix-multiplication, multiplication, numpy-ndarray

I need a simple numpy function do this multiplication without a *for-loop* and more time efficient.

Actually I want a function that multiplies each row of `a` to `b`

```
a=np.arange(2,12).reshape(5,2)
b=np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])
c=np.array([[a[i,:]@b] for i in range(a.shape[0])])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With [numpy.tensordot](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.tensordot.html#numpy.tensordot):

```
c = np.tensordot(a, b, axes=1)
```

If you insist that `shape` will be the same:

```
c.reshape(5,1,2)
```

Comment: that returns exactly what i want

Comment: This is definitely the neatest answer, but note that tensordot is about 10 times slower (on my machine at least) than using einsum. It also seem to be a bit slower than the OPs original method.

Comment: @MattPitkin Thank you for your interesting insight. I personally still find it difficult to understand how `einsum` works. Glad to see that both answers appear.

Answer (score 1):

Using numpy [einsum](http://ajcr.net/Basic-guide-to-einsum/) you could do (edited to reshape the array based on @dobkind's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53191702/1862861)):

```
c = np.einsum('ki,ij->kj', a, b).reshape(5,1,2)
```

which should be faster.

```
%timeit np.einsum('ki,ij->kj', a, b).reshape(5,1,2)
1.87 µs ± 10.5 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

versus (using the `@` matrix multiplication operator, which works in Python 3)

```
%timeit np.array([[a[i,:]@b] for i in range(a.shape[0])])
10.2 µs ± 36.7 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

Comment: I run your suggestion but it's answer is not as same as what I want

Comment: Try np.einsum('ki,ij->kj', a, b) - I've edited the answer to this option. Also @dobkind's answer works.

Answer (score 1):

To use `@`, make `a` a 3d array (5,1,2) with pairs well with (2,2) (or (1,2,2) by automatic broadcasting).

```
In [448]: np.array([[a[i,:]@b] for i in range(a.shape[0])])
Out[448]: 
array([[[11, 16]],

       [[19, 28]],

       [[27, 40]],

       [[35, 52]],

       [[43, 64]]])

In [450]: a[:,None,:]@b
Out[450]: 
array([[[11, 16]],

       [[19, 28]],

       [[27, 40]],

       [[35, 52]],

       [[43, 64]]])
```

This is actually a bit faster than the `einsum` solution - though with a example this small I wouldn't make a big deal about timings.

Answer (score 0):

Use matmul function from numpy to multiply two matrices.
Let me know whether this helps. Thank you.

```
c = np.matmul(a,b)
```

Comment: I really appreciate your cooperation but this  is not work for my application

Comment: also @ is matmul